# Can member functions of class templates be inlined in case of explicit instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, inline, instantiation

Can `doSth()` be inlined given this configuration?

```
// A.h

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    void doSth();
};


// A.cpp

template<typename T>
void A<T>::doSth() { /* do something */ }

template class A<bool>;
template class A<int>;


// main.cpp

#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    A<bool> a;
    a.doSth();
}
```

If the answer is negative I'd go define my member functions in a .tpp file and include that at the end of "A.h" but that would just look weird with the non-inline versions in a .cpp file so I'd want to avoid that.

Comment: Don't forget that Whole Program Optimisation/Link-Time Code Generation can "inline" even stuff that compilation alone cannot.

Comment: @RichardHodges  I don't think I can conduct a reasonable test for this. I'd need to take into account multiple platforms too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most compilers cannot inline with that arrangement of code.  The ICC compiler documentation claims it supports being invoked in a way that would enable that inlining **AFTER** you first built a different way, then gathered profiling data then fed back the profiling data to a cross module optimizing build.  I made only modest attempts to get that to work and it worked only in play size projects, not in anything real.

For use with ordinary compilation, you should have that extra file for the function definitions you want inline, but you should probably not include it in the end of A.h, rather include A.h in the beginning of it and include it in select cpp files that really need it.

I prefer

```
// A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    inline void doSth();
};
#endif

// A.tpp
#ifndef A_TPP
#define A_TPP
#include "A.h"
template<typename T>
inline void A<T>::doSth() { /* do something */ }
#endif

// Various other .h files that need to know what is declared in A
#include "A.h"

// Only cpp files that need what is defined in A.tpp
#include "A.tpp"
```

I forget the option as well as which compilers have such an option, but that nearly redundant use of `inline` in the .h file goes with a compiler option saying that in case the function is declared that way **and** used **and** not defined, throw a compile time error.

Without that option, the link time error is harder to read but does tell you which .cpp needed to include the .tpp but missed it.

Comment: So as I see I should only rely on the kind of inlining in question if I find my particular compiler support the feature you mentioned explicitly. Separate inclusion for the functions-to-be-inlined seems rather tedious to me (unless they are really that rarely used, which is not my case). I think I'll put the definitions into the class's then. If those functions need to grow then I think I'll go with my plan B.

Comment: Maybe your template classes have less circular relationships than in the code I need to maintain!  In the code I maintain, `B` might massively depend on `A` and it might take a lot of care just to make the function declarations of `A` depend only on predeclaration of `B`.  The functions definitions of `A` need a full definition of `B`.  So without that file split I suggested, the circularity makes compilation impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You most definitely can. You also forgot the `;` at the end of your struct definition.

```
struct a
{
    // Whatever
};
```

Is how it should be.

Comment: Can you elaborate why it can? The compiler cannot see the definition at the point of call, after all.

Comment: It's more of a linker question. Initially the compiler can leave that as an empty place that the linker can choose to inject the code. For example, try the above by instantiating A<char*> and it's the linker that complains and not the compiler.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see inlined. It most definitely can compile though.

Comment: fuzzythink44, I confirmed by looking at disassembly that VS does support it when built in "Release" mode. In-lining in general is compiler specific, a compiler may decide something is too complex to inline. Also, it depends on your compiler flags (optimized for size vs speed etc).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does allow in-lining in this way but it limits the types that you can instantiate to just those that you defined in your A.cpp file.

Comment: That limitation after explicit instantiation I think applies to all compilers.